# Continuity set and his preimage in $f$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\pi$ is probability measures on $(X,\mathscr{B}\left(X\right))$, where $\mathscr{B}\left(X\right)$ is borel $\sigma\text{-algebra}$ on $X$. Consider the set of all continuity sets in $\mathscr{B}\left(X\right)$. It means that consider set of all $B\in\mathscr{B}\left(X\right)$ such, that $\pi(\partial B)=0$. Morover consider that $f:X\to X$ is borel measurable function, it means that $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}\left(X\right); f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X; f(x)\in B\}\in \mathscr{B}\left(X\right)$.

I would like to know if it is true that the preimage of continuity set in $f$ is continuity set. In other words, if the set $A=f^{-1}(B)$, where $B$ is continuity set, is also continuity set.

I have no idea how to start. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \geq 0, 0$ for $x <0$. Let $\pi$ be any probability measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb  R$ such that $\pi (\{1\})=0$ and $\pi (\{0\}) \neq 0$. (For example, $\pi$ could be the delta measure at $0$). Then $\{1\}$ is a continuity set but $f^{-1}(\{1\}) =[0,\infty)$ is not, since the boundary of $[0,\infty)$ is $\{0\}$.

Even continuity of  $f$  is not enough. Take $f(x)=x+1$ with the measure $\pi$ described above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can be made some assumption to $f$, for example $f $ is continuous and then, it will be true?

Comment: @Waney If $f$ is a homeomorphism then it i true. Just contunuity is not enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, if I can ask can you give me some counter example when the continuity is not enough. And can you recommend me some source or literature where I can find more about this, for example why the homeomorphism is enough. Finally I will need to cite it in my thesis so I would like to have some relevant source.

Comment: I am sorry but I am little bit confused. If I am correct, the homeomorphism $f$ is defined as $f$ is bijection, is continuous and inverse function is also continuous. The function $x+1$ in your answer is then homeomorphism, but you give it as a counter example. And morover, how I know that measure of $f^{-1}(F)$ is aslo $0$ (not all homeorphisms are measure preserving).

Comment: Sorry! $f$ has to be a measure preserving homeomorhism, not just a homeomorhism. @Waney